# Hibbernate mapping map without joincolumn/jointable

Tags: java, hibernate, dictionary, mapping, persistence

Try example from "7.2.2.2. Maps" from Hibernate 4.3 documentation, where I have two entities:

```
@Entity
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    String number;

    @ManyToOne
    private Customer customer;

    //getters/setters
}

@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @MapKey(name = "number")
    private Map<String, Order> orders;

    //getters/setters
}
```

With adding `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` it's starts save order entities, but properties `number` and `customer` still save like `null`

How I am try to save:

```
session.beginTransaction();
Map<String, Order> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("0", new Order());
map.put("1", new Order());
map.put("2", new Order());
map.put("3", new Order());
Customer customer = new Customer();
customer.setOrders(map);
session.save(customer);
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not initializing `number` property of you orders anywhere and since default value for type `String` is `null` thus you get a null value in db.

Comment: I'm rethink this functionality, and I was wrong. How to say it correctly. This functionality for load mapped map, but not for auto-filling of properties.